# A problem with implementing PCA-guided k-means

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca, python, k-means

I am new to machine learning. I am reading the papers [K-means Clustering via Principal Component Analysis](http://ranger.uta.edu/~chqding/papers/KmeansPCA1.pdf) and [PCA-guided search for K-means](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865514003675). But there are too many mathematical proofs in these papers. I can't understand these papers easily. Can anyone explain this thing in simple words?

Also, I am trying to use Python to experiment with this approach. But the result is far form the paper.

My code is below. I use the `The AT&T Face Data Set` dataset.

```
TRAIN_PEOPLE = 40
MAX_ITER = 1000
# k-means starting

print("method       Sum of distances")
pca = PCA(n_components = TRAIN_PEOPLE).fit(X)
pca_result = KMeans(n_clusters=TRAIN_PEOPLE, max_iter = MAX_ITER).fit(pca.transform(X))
kmeans = KMeans(init=pca_result.cluster_centers_.dot(pca.components_), 
     n_clusters=TRAIN_PEOPLE, n_init=1, max_iter = MAX_ITER).fit(X)

print("pca-guided   " + str(kmeans.inertia_))

kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=TRAIN_PEOPLE, n_init=1, max_iter = MAX_ITER).fit(X)
print("k-means++    " + str(kmeans.inertia_))


kmeans = KMeans(init='random', n_clusters=TRAIN_PEOPLE, n_init=1, max_iter = MAX_ITER).fit(X)
print("random       " + str(kmeans.inertia_))
```

Here is the result:

```
method       Sum of distances
pca-guided   214982166.562   // too high!
k-means++    161294842.543
random       170072750.47
```

Could anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Re the first paper see here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183236. Does it help?

Comment: @amoeba yes.But why the experiment result is wrong ?

Comment: k-means is randomized. Maybe you were just unluckym Try multiple runs!

Comment: yes.I tried.the same result.

Comment: When you transform cluster centroids in the PCA space to the original space, don't you forget to add the variable means?