# Is there a JackStraw equivalent for clustering?

Tags: clustering, pca

The JackStraw is a method to get honest p-values for correlations between variables and principal components derived from those variables.

[JackStraw paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2014/10/21/bioinformatics.btu674.full.pdf)

There is a close relationship between PCA and clustering: K clusters gives you a signal in the top K-1 principal components, as outlined  in this paper on [PCA for detecting population substructure in genetic data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1713260/). There is a more thorough and less sloppy discussion in [this CV thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183236/what-is-the-relation-between-k-means-clustering-and-pca).

Does anyone know of a JackStraw equivalent that gives honest p-values for correlations between variables and cluster indicators? Preferably for an arbitrary clustering method and an arbitrary two-sample test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This new preprint, "Statistical Significance of Cluster Membership with Applications to High-Throughput Genomic Data" answers your question. It tests association between variables and their computed cluster centers:
https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/02/23/248633

The developmental version of the jackstraw R package includes these new functionalities. There's a dedicated and refined function for k-means clustering, as well as one that should work with a range of arbitrary clustering methods:
https://github.com/ncchung/jackstraw

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?