# Feature selection in the presence of extremely large feature set

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, small-sample

Suppose you have a very large feature set (1000s to 1000,000 features) when building a machine learning model. How do you go about selecting the features?

I know of the following methods for feature selection when the number of features is not extremely large:
(1) (supervised) PCA
(2) Lasso
(3) ElasticNet
(4) Forward step-wise selection

Comment: Related to (4), step-wise VIF exclusion can be used to get rid of variables with high multicollinearity

Comment: A nice article (which you have probably read), [is found here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/).

Comment: In the ML domain, some individuals have had success with autoencoders, which act as a way to select features from data.  Several variations exist, all of which allow you to input a large number of features and output a smaller number before running all of your data through a complex neural network.

Comment: You may also want to look into some methods to reduce noise before implementing these methods (if your data are noisy, like market data).  I've seen good results with Wavelet transform.

Comment: Clustering (kMeans, hierarchical) may also return results you are looking for, giving you similar results to PCA, though [as we can see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/183236/213806), the two methods are distinct.

Comment: [Another interesting paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf) goes over a number of "feature selection" or data compression methods.  Sorry for all of the comments, got sucked into a wormhole.