# A method to separate classes while taking variable dependence into account

Tags: classification, model, group-differences, supervised-learning

I have posted [a question related to this problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372714/r-is-there-a-method-similar-to-pca-that-incorperates-dependence) over a year ago and we still were not able to figure this out.

We have two groups, **A** and **B** that we want to train on to separate them. Both have numerous observations of "text" so for example:

group **A**:

- AAABBBC*CAAAAAAAC
- CCCBBBC*CAAAAAAAB
- CBBBBBC*CAAAAAAAB

group **B**:

- AAACCCC*CAAAAAAAA
- CCCCCCC*CAAAAAAAA
- CBBCCCC*CAAAAAAAA

Notably, our original datasets are much larger, with around 4,000 observations for **A** (with really specific patterns) and around 20,000 for group **B**. 
We want is a model that sees things like:

- if there is a `C` at position 1 we see a `B` on the end in group **A** (2/3), and we do not see this in group **B** (0/3)
- That we only find the motif `AAABBB` in group **A**
- if we see `AAABBB` we also saw a `C` at the end in group **A** (1/3) but we did not see this in group **B** (0/3)

We tried LDA now (after converting this data to binary vectors), however, this would score each letter independently. To illustrate if group **A** would have two subgroups:

- `sub1`: position1 = A + position10 = C
- `sub2`: position2 = A + position15 = B

and both are not common in group **B** then a method like LDA would also score position1 = A (`sub1`) + position15 = B (`sub2`) extremely high even tho they are actually part of different dependencies within group **A**, so we are looking for an alternative taking care of such dependencies when differentiating groups.

We really hope someone here can help us out!

**EDIT**

---

To explain the dependencies better as asked by @carlo I made a grossly simplified example:
[image]
For pink we see that:

- A at pos `1` is often associated with A at pos `3`
- A at pos `1` can also be associated with B at pos `2` where it is often followed by A at `3` and less often by C at pos `3`

For blue we see that:

- A at pos `1` is often associated with A at pos `2` and then sometimes followed by C at `3`.

Then when we run a classifier we want it to see that a sequence such as A**X**A would be probably group I but that a sequence such as ABA is even more likely to be group I, and that a sequence such as AAB would be group II.

Comment: care to explain better what do you mean by "dependence"?

Comment: @carlo please see my edit, hopefully it's more clear now!