# Are the original features a linear combination of the principal components?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

In PCA, we often think of the principal components / eigenvectors as a linear combination of the original features in vector space. Is the reverse true as well, i.e., is each feature a linear combination of the principal components?

Comment: Do you mean *exactly* or *approximately?*

Comment: @whuber Hmm, I originally meant theoretically, so exactly. But your question makes me think that the answer is "no" to exactly, but that it can be approximately written as a linear combination of the PCs, so I would be interested in that answer as well.

Comment: The answer depends on how many PCs you retain.  The whole idea behind PCA is to approximate the original features using a smaller number of PCs.  By taking all the PCs, nothing is lost.  Have you looked at our [higher voted threads on PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca?tab=Votes)

Comment: @whuber Yup. It's actually this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183236/what-is-the-relation-between-k-means-clustering-and-pca one that inspired my question. The answer by amoeba says "The intuition is that PCA seeks to represent all $n$ data vectors as linear combinations of a small number of eigenvectors, and does it to minimize the mean-squared reconstruction error." I've never seen it phrased this way before, but it seems to be saying the features are represented as a linear combination of the PCs.

Comment: That's right.  That's the basis of just about every plot of PCs that has ever been produced: the data are approximated as points in a space spanned by two (or sometimes three) PCs.