# Is variable contribution to the top principal components a valid method to asses variable importance in a k-means clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, k-means

If the answer is no, could someone give a simple counterexample?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify the interplay between PCA and k-means in your setup? Are you running PCA then k-means?

Comment: Hi. I am running a k-means clustering algorithm using 20 variables. Separately I am using PCA analysis to obtain the first two principal components, and checking which of my variables contributed the most to those principal components. Asking if those variables are also the ones that have more weight in the k-means clustering process. Thanks

Comment: How do you determine variable weight in k-means?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know (how to estimate the weight of each variable in the k-means). I am asking if checking the variables that contribute to the top Principal Components is a valid approximation.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You will probably find useful information in this [related thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/183236/930). If this is the case, then I believe this thread should be closed as a duplicate. Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed that thread addresses my question