# Relations between clustering, graph-theory and principal components

Tags: clustering, pca, graph-theory

I am trying to give some theoretical foundations to the intuitive idea that three branches of mathematics are indeed tightly connected, specifically: clustering, graph-theory and principal components.

I would like to post this as a very open question, without commenting too much on why I believe these fields are connected, so that everyone can freely elaborate according to their intuition or academic knowledge.

On a high-level, clustering is aimed at separating objects into groups by making the objects belonging to the same group as similar as possible to each other.

Graph-theory, instead, tries to topologically represent the relationships between several objects. As such, the relative location of an object in a space is dependent on its similarity to neighbour objects. Somewhere, I have even read: "Clustering: an application of Minimum Spanning Tree"!

Finally, the link between clustering and PCA has been well discussed here:

[What is the relation between k-means clustering and PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183236/what-is-the-relation-between-k-means-clustering-and-pca)

So my question is: is there any proven mathematical link between these fields? it would be great if someone could also share references to academic papers that explored these connections.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question that deserves a thoughtful answer, but I will simply comment that there is somewhat of an apples-to-apples comparison being made. Graph-theory is indeed a field of mathematics. On the other hand, clustering is a body of statistical techniques, and PCA is a specific way to perform (unsupervised) dimensionality reduction.